# Loop in C to increment value

Tags: c

I did some experiment, pulling my hair out to figure the solution, please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int USD , JPY;
    int lower,upper,skip;

    lower = 1;  
    upper = 1000;   
    skip = 50;  

    USD = lower;
    while (USD <= upper) {
    JPY = USD * 114;

    printf("%d\t\%d\n", USD, JPY);
    USD = USD + skip;

    }

}
```

Results :

```
1       114
51      5814
101     11514
151     17214
etc
```

My expected result is below :

```
1         114      
50        5700       ----> incremented by 49
100       11400      -----> incremented by 50
150       17100      -----> incremented by 50 and same with the rest, all incremented by 50
```

Comment: How can you expect result to be 50 if your summing 50 + 1?

Comment: `USD = USD + skip - (USD == lower);`

Comment: @pmg Why `== lower`? It still only works for `lower == 1`. To make it general, you'd need `USD = USD + skip - (USD == lower ? lower : 0);`.

Comment: Right @EOF. I'll include your content in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result which you are getting is correct according to your code. It is because,initially     USD=1 and in the first iteration, when you do     USD=USD+skip , it actually means    USD=1+50=51. 
At the end of the second iteration,    USD=101 because    USD=51+50 and similarly in all the other iterations     USD is increased with 50.

For getting the result which you expect, you have to replace    USD=USD+50 with the following code in your loop:

```
if(USD==1)
  USD=USD+49;
else
  USD=USD+50;
```

By performing this,you will get the expected answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
USD = USD + skip - (USD == 1);
```

This works when `lower` is 1.
If you want to make it general for every `lower` you need, as pointed by @EOF

```
USD = USD + skip - (USD == lower ? lower : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

never forget the power of debuging in asking quenstion. whenever you see that the out put is not the same as what you expected, simply debug.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int USD , JPY;
    int lower,upper,skip;

    lower = 1;  
    upper = 1000;   
    skip = 50;  

    USD = lower;
do {
    JPY = USD * 114;

    printf("%d\t\%d\n", USD, JPY);
    USD = lower * skip;
lower ++;
   } while (USD <= upper);
```